# Is there a way to define a static String array from strings.xml

Tags: java, android

I want to declare a static string array using an array in `strings.xml`.

```
private static final String[] tip_types = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tip_types_array);
```

but you cannot use `getResources()` 'in a static context'. Is there a way to do this or must I not use a static variable?

Obviously

```
private final String[] tip_types = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tip_types_array);
```

works, but then the declared array is not static.

Comment: why do you really need a static string[] better create a static method returning Sting[] and pass context or resource object to pick the desired array

Comment: You can have it be `static`, but it cannot be `final`, and you would need to be able to initialize it at some point when you have a `Context`.

Comment: I was being an idiot! I was trying to move a hard cosed declaration from the start of my code into strings.xml. Everything after the `=` was the explicit declaration so I was just trying to replace that with code. That was the wrong approach. I have now moved the `getResources...` into the code that actually uses the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch resources (including strings) you always need a context. When you create a static field, even within an Activity, you cannot access the instance fields and therefore there's no context available.

You have two options to solve the problem:

**Method 1**
You can create an Application class that stores the application context in a static field upon creation and get your string array using the application context.

```
private final static String[] tip_types = YourApplicationClass.getAppContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tip_types_array);
```

**Method 2**
You can create a getter for your static variable where you pass a context. Like a singleton you check if the array is already resolved, and return it right away or fetch is using the supplied context. This has the advantage of lazy initialisation, the array is only created when it's actually needed.

```
private static String[] tip_types;

private static String[] getTipTypes(Context context) {
    if(tip_types == null) {
        tip_types = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tip_types_array);
    }
    return tip_types;
}
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it explains nicely why what I was trying didn't work - even though my problem was that I was trying to do the wrong thing in the first place! (See my comment to my original question)

Answer (score 0):

The first one, you need declare a NfcApplication custom class which extend from Application class:

```
public final class NfcApplication extends Application {

    private static NfcApplication sApplication;

    public static NfcApplication getInstance() {
        return sApplication;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        sApplication = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();

        sApplication = null;
    }
}
```

The second one, then you can call the context by this way

```
private static final String[] ARRAY_LIST = NfcApplication.getInstance().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.label_unit_array_str);
```